# Integrating CKEditor in ASP.NET MVC 2?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, ckeditor

I want to use CKEditor for a comment field in my ASP.NET MVC 2 application, but can't get it to work. Here is what I have:

The textarea where I try to integrate the editor:

```
    <div class="editor-field">
        <%: Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Comment, new { @class = "textarea", @id="Editor1" })%>
        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Comment) %>
    </div>
```

The script references in the head:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/ckeditor/ckeditor.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</asp:Content>
```

And the document ready function:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm())
   {%>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function () {
           $('#Editor1').ckeditor();
       });
   </script>
```

(Etc...)
I don't know if the problem is with the TextareaFor helper method, where I tried to set the id to Editor1. I'm pretty new to MVC as well, so I guessed this was how to do it.

Anyway, it doesn't work, and I would appreciate any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Do you get any javascript error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, found the answer myself. It appears there was a conflict with another jQuery plugin on the same page, so I needed to use jQuery.noConflict(); and then use jQuery instead of $ in the code. The placement of noConflict was also important. See the comment by erhard on this web page: http://devoracles.com/jquery-error-documentready-is-not-a-function-sure

Comment: that comment is no longer accessible. what was it?

Answer (score 0):

first check if `$('#Editor1')` is returning the element you want.

```
alert($('#Editor1').length);
alert($('#Editor1')[0].id);
```

if not, try using a class selector instead, like `$('.ckeditor')`

Comment: Yes it is. But when I check the debugger in Chrome, I get the error message "Uncaught TypeError: Object #<an Object> has no method 'ckeditor'". I'm new to jQuery so I don't know what I'm doing wrong here.